# ¿Como escribir los datos de un archivo csv en un TextEdit?

Tags: python, csv, pyqt5, qt-designer

tengo un archivo csv, en el tengo varios datos pero quiero que se muestren en un TextEdit de qtdesigener.  Ya logre que se escriba correctamente pero el problema va con lo que escribe.

Y es que lo que escribe es esto: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='productos.csv'

Ya intente con los modos r y w y con ninguno muestra el contenido del archivo.

Este es mi codigo :

```
    with open("productos.csv", 'w') as login:
        print(login)
        self.textEdit_9.setPlainText(str(login))
        login.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varios problemas:

1. Estas abriendo el archivo de escritura ("w"), con lo cual inmediatamente eliminas su contenido. Debes abrirlo de lectura ("r").
2. `login` es el archivo; debes usar una operación para leerlo. Hay varias alternativas, y en este caso lo más lógico es usar un `for` para obtener línea por línea.
3. Cada línea leída trae un "\r" al final. Debes aplicar `strip()` para descartar todos los *white spaces* al principio y al final de la cadena.
4. El `close` está demás, ya que cuando usas `with`, el archivo se cierra automáticamente al terminar el bloque.

En resumen, la manera correcta de leerlo es:

```
with open("clientes.csv", 'r') as login:
    for linea in login:
        linea = linea.strip()
        print(linea)
        self.textEdit_9.setPlainText(linea)
```

**Cómo leer un archivo .CSV**

Adicionalmente, no estás usando la manera correcta de leer un archivo .CSV. Tú simplemente lo lees como un archivo de texto: lees y recuperas una línea completa de texto en bruto.

Veamos este archivo .CSV:

```
user_id, user_name
jaime2000, Jaime Cortez
s_olmos, Santiago Olmos
```

La primera línea tiene los nombres de las columnas.

Tal como lo lees, obtendrás tres valores, correspondientes a las tres
líneas del archivo. Sin embargo, tienes la posibilidad de pasarle el archivo a un lector CSV especializado, de los cuales hay varios.

El más simple es `csv.reader`, que se limita a dividir la línea guiándose por las comas y retorna una lista por cada línea:

```
import csv

with open('clientes.csv', 'r') as file:
    # Preparar un lector .CSV a partir del archivo.
    csvFile = csv.reader(file)
    # displaying the contents of the CSV file
    for lines in csvFile:
        print(lines)
```

produce:

```
['user_id', ' user_name']
['jaime2000', ' Jaime Cortez']
['s_olmos', ' Santiago Olmos']
```

Mejor aún, puedes usar `csv.DictReader`, que te retorna un diccionario por cada línea. Las llaves del diccionario son el contenido de la primera fila del archivo:

```
import csv

with open("clientes.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for linea in reader:
        print(linea)
```

produce:

```
{'user_id': 'jaime2000', ' user_name': ' Jaime Cortez'}
{'user_id': 's_olmos', ' user_name': ' Santiago Olmos'}
```

Fijate que la primera línea ya no aparece en la salida; la usó `DictReader` para extraer las llaves del diccionario.

Ahora, ya que tienes un diccionario, puedes recuperar directamente el campo deseado:

```
import csv

with open("clientes.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for linea in reader:
        print(linea['user_id'])
```

produce:

```
jaime2000
s_olmos
```

Comment: Gracias compañero por responder, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema y es que no sigue escribiendose en el qtextedit, eso ya es muy raro y ya me confundi porque verifique la variable y si es un string ya esta muy raro eso ya no se que hacer.